# R_function Nnet_How can I solve the following error "the object (list) can not be automatically converted in integer"?

Tags: r, type-conversion, nnet

I am trying to use a neural network algorithm to solve a statistical problem. When I call the function Nnet (software R) with the following parameters :

```
rn=nnet(resignation~., data=T[,-1], entropy=T, size=5, decay=1, MaxNWts=3000, maxit=1000)
```

I have the error below, and I don't succeed to understand the meaning of this error and how to solve it:

> weights:  2656
>
> Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, ...) :
> l'objet (list) ne peut être converti automatiquement en un type 'integer'
>
> Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, ...) :
> the object (list) can not be automatically converted to an 'integer' type

Could you please help me ?

I remain available for any further information
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the main problem is the fact that you use the name `T` as your data frame name. As a consequence, the value received by the `entropy` argument is a list (data frames can be seen as lists in R) instead of a boolean (or integer). To make it work, run this instead:

```
rn=nnet(Species~., data=T[,-1], entropy=TRUE, size=5, decay=1, MaxNWts=3000, maxit=1000)
```

**N.B:** I would suggest you not to use `T` as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Comment: I changed the data frame name with T5 and saved the variable "resignation" as a factor :

Comment: rn=nnet(resignation~., data=T5[,-1], entropy=TRUE, size=5, decay=1, MaxNWts=3000, maxit=1000)

Comment: Nevertheless I have a new error linked with entropy argument : Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, entropy = TRUE, ...) : formal argument "entropy" corresponds to several furnished arguments

Comment: Could you please help me ?

Comment: Try to use the argument `softmax = TRUE`. Tell me if this helped.

Comment: It didn't work, so I restarted from beginning and let the variable resignation as numeric (not as a factor). Then I used your first proposition : rn=nnet(resignation~., data=T5[,-1], entropy=TRUE, size=5, decay=1, MaxNWts=3000, maxit=1000)  : it works !

Comment: Now I have a last question about Nnet() function : is it necessary to standardise variables of the database before using Nnet function ? or the function includes this step before estimating the weights of the neural network ?
In fact, if I am right, variables must be standardised to use a neural network algorithm.

Comment: Ok great. It is better to have normalized input for different reasons, for example if you have attributes that lie in different ranges of values.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Are you agree the function Nnet creates itself as many input neurons as modalities for qualitative variables ? (I don't have to do this step by myself before using the function : ie. transforme qualitatives variables in binomial variable)